# Manage and update many machines with the same settings

Tags: macos, mobile-device-management

I have a small renderfarm of mac minis and they should all have exactly the same settings, get the same updates, etc. etc. I'm sure there is a solution for this and I would love to stop repeating myself :). How does this work at the enterprise level?

EDIT:
Sorry for being vague. I have just four computers currently but may expand, though likely staying below ten. I frequently have to install software upgrades, configure licenses, update network mount points, etc.

I've done some rudimentary google searches but am having trouble finding the terminology.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Is small 1000 units? What's your budget? What's your cost for labor? Please edit this so we can know what your constraints are. I'd start with a [free hosted MDM like bushel](http://www.bushel.com?r=7f99dcf5859e4ebea0b95285edfb07f1) and then refine your search by doing research on options.

Comment: This question is pretty broad. If you want them set up the same way, set up  one and clone the others. You can distribute different kinds of settings via OS X server and do batch-tasks via Apple Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that level of computers, your best bet is to get a license of Apple Remote Desktop to manage them.

- https://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/

Since it's Apple software, you can leverage AppleCare to get technical help and guidance. It scales very well for situations under 50 computers. Even managing thousands of Macs is possible, but I'd put my money on a different horse when crossing 100 Macs under management.

Seriously consider trying out bushel as well as osquery along with ARD to get started.

- https://osquery.io
- http://www.bushel.com

You get free support from bushel and can stick with the free plan to see if it suits you while learning about MDM options. ARD is a no brainer to help install and manage without messing with setting up screen sharing one by one. Your call if OS Query is worth learning - if you don't want to know SQL like languages, there are other free solutions like Munki and AutoPkg to explore.

- https://www.munki.org/munki/
- https://autopkg.github.io/autopkg/